# How do I capture session/cookie data from WebSphere Commerce?

Tags: websphere, websphere-commerce

all.

I'm trying to extract session data out of WebSphere Commerce Server 7. Being new to this platform (with a general understanding of Struts) I was wondering if someone can point me to an approach whereby introducing a servlet filter or maybe extending a command can allow me to capture any user session data (shopping cart items, wishlist...etc). What I'm trying to do is extract those into another system in order to run some analytics against them. Is this something possible to do with WCS? Or is that kind of data spread all over commands and written/read to/from the database each time?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you clarify specifics about why you want the info?  Much of it may be available thru the analytics.

Comment: I'm integrating it with another system

Comment: I understand you are integrating, but you may be able to expose some of this data, which data specifically are you trying to expose with the cart and the wishlist?

Comment: Just which product ID's or item id's are in the shopping cart.

Comment: In that case do what Abed said, and use the OrderDataBean and OrderItemDataBean to get back what is in the shopping cart.

Answer (score 1):

if you are in a DataBean than extend/implements SmartDataBeanImpl/SmartDataBean , you can get session object by

```
getHttpRequest().getSession()
```

below is away to get HTTPServletRequest if you are in Controller command

```
((HttpControllerRequestObject)(((ViewCommandContext) commandContext).getRequest())).getHttpRequest()
```

and of course you can get the session from request as above .

I don't believe WCS save wishlist / shopping cart info in session , instead you need to write your own APIs/Helpers to retrieve these info to you and you might save them in session/request properties .. refer to Aurora shipping cart / whishlist jsp to how you can get these info .

I hope this help you for what you need

Thanks
Abed

Comment: Thank you, Abed! is there a specific design pattern used when writing helpers?

Comment: No - Helpers always have Static methods that you can call without object instantiations . make sure that static method use only parameters passed to that method and use its own local variables .